# Watch window for XCode debugging

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

Is there any watch window to see variable value in XCode during debugging?
Can we check value just typing variable name as in watch window?

On mouse over, I can't see value for dictionary type objects. 
I see "Variables View" option but it has only first option enabled.
in "Debugger" window, I can't type variable name.
Watchpoint stops your program when the value of an expression changes. But I have to see value during breakpoint.

Let me know what is the best way to debug.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Expression window.  Run:Show:Expressions...  Just type in the entry field the variable name or expression .  You can also right click/hold on a variable name and in the drop-down menu select "Add to Expression Window".

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can click the two little arrows in the mouseover description and select print. You can then see what the dictionary contains in the console.

Comment: Holy non-obvious feature!  Thanks, this is exactly what I've been looking for. I'm shocked that I did not find this command sooner.